# How to get result of successfully submitted transaction?

Tags: transactions, java-sdk

I am using the Stellar Java SDK to submit a `PathPaymentStrictReceiveOperation` transaction. I get back a `SubmitTransactionResponse` object. I would like to get the results of the (successful) transaction, specifically I would like to find out how much was actually sent and received (the equivalent of `PathPaymentBaseOperationResponse`) but I cannot see how to achieve that using the SDK.

I see that `SubmitTransactionResponse` has a `getResultXdr()` method, and using the decoder at https://laboratory.stellar.org/#xdr-viewer? I can see that has the information I want to access from the code, but I do not see any method in the SDK which would allow me to decode the result.

Anyone have any hints, or sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question in case it is useful to someone else in future. You seem to need to use the classes from package *org.stellar.sdk.xdr* even though that package is undocumented in the [Java SDK](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/).

Here is an example:

```
 SubmitTransactionResponse tr = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
 if (tr.usSuccess()) {
            Optional<TransactionResult> optionalDecodedTransactionResult = tr.getDecodedTransactionResult();
            TransactionResult decodedTransactionResult = optionalDecodedTransactionResult.get();
            TransactionResult.TransactionResultResult result = decodedTransactionResult.getResult();
            OperationResult opInner = result.getResults()[0];
            OperationResult.OperationResultTr tr1 = opInner.getTr();
            PathPaymentStrictReceiveResult pathPaymentStrictReceiveResult = tr1.getPathPaymentStrictReceiveResult();
            PathPaymentStrictReceiveResult.PathPaymentStrictReceiveResultSuccess success = pathPaymentStrictReceiveResult.getSuccess();
            SimplePaymentResult last = success.getLast();
            Int64 amount = last.getAmount();
            System.out.println("Amount="+amount.getInt64());
            ClaimOfferAtom[] offers = success.getOffers();
            for (var offer : offers) {
                Int64 amountBought = offer.getAmountBought();
                Int64 amountSold = offer.getAmountSold();
                Int64 offerID = offer.getOfferID();
                Asset assetBought = Asset.fromXdr(offer.getAssetBought());
                System.out.println(amountBought.getInt64()+" "+amountSold.getInt64()+" "+offerID.getInt64()+" "+assetBought);
            }
 }
```